# Solve a system of equations with $\ln$ exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2^{\ln x}=3^{\ln y}$$,

$$(3x)^{\ln 4}=(2y)^{\ln 5}$$

I have tried exponentiation, but I seem to go in circles.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Rather than exponentiation, try taking logarithm.

For example the first equation would become $$\color{blue}{(\ln x)}\ln 2 = \color{green}{(\ln y )}( \ln 3)\tag{1}$$

Do the same thing for the second equation too, then you can solve simultaneous equation to obtain $\ln x$ and $\ln y$.

Edit:

For the second equation:

$$(\ln 4) (\ln 3 + \ln x) = (\ln 5) (\ln 2 + \ln y)$$

Rearranging, we have

$$ (\ln 4)(\ln x) - (\ln 5) (\ln y) = (\ln 5) (\ln 2) - \ln 4 \ln 3$$

$$2(\ln 2)\color{blue}{(\ln x)} - (\ln 5)\color{green}{ \ln y} = (\ln 2)(\ln 5-2\ln 3)\tag{2}$$

Comment: so 2nd equation would be (ln 4)ln 3x=(ln 5)ln 2y)    i don't know what to do from there.

Comment: Edited, as you can see, we have two linear equations in terms of $\ln x$ and $\ln y$.

Comment: I don't see how to solve for x and y.

Comment: Solve for $\ln x$ and $\ln y$ first, once you know those, then you can take exponentiation to recover $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It seems like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

As the log function is injective, you can take the log of both sides; that is,

$$2^{\ln{x}}=3^{\ln{y}} \iff \ln{2^{\ln{x}}}=\ln{3^{\ln{y}}} \iff \ln{x}\cdot \ln{2}=\ln{y}\cdot \ln{3}$$

NOTE that it is crucial that the log function is injective for the application of this method.

To solve, assume $x=e^z>0$ and $y=e^w>0$ thus

$$\ln{e^z}\cdot \ln{2}=\ln{e^w}\cdot \ln{3} \iff z\cdot \ln{e}\cdot \ln{2}=w \cdot \ln{e}\cdot \ln{3} \iff z \cdot \ln{2}=w\cdot \ln{3} \iff$$ $$\frac{z}{w}=\frac{\ln{3}}{\ln{2}}$$

Thus all the solutions are:

$$z=w\frac{\ln{3}}{\ln{2}}$$ or $$w=z\frac{\ln{2}}{\ln{3}}$$

and since $z=\ln{x}$  and $w=\ln{y}$:

$$z=\frac{\ln{3}}{\ln{2}}e^y \iff x=e^{\frac{\ln{3}}{\ln{2}}\ln{y}}$$

or

$$w=\frac{\ln{2}}{\ln{3}}e^x \iff y=e^{\frac{\ln{2}}{\ln{3}}\ln{x}}$$

here is a graph of the solution

[image]

For the second equation you can proceed in the same way and try to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly solve as follow:

$$2^{\ln x}=3^{\ln y} \iff {\ln x}\cdot{\ln 2}={\ln y}\cdot{\ln 3}$$

$$(3x)^{\ln 4}=(2y)^{\ln 5}\iff {\ln 3x}\cdot{\ln 4}={\ln 2y}\cdot{\ln 5} \iff ({\ln x}+{\ln 3})\cdot{\ln 4}=({\ln y}+{\ln 2})\cdot{\ln 5}$$

that is:

$$$$\begin{cases}
{\ln x}\cdot{\ln 2}-{\ln y}\cdot{\ln 3}=0 \\
{\ln x}\cdot{\ln 4}-{\ln y}\cdot{\ln 5}={\ln 2}\cdot{\ln 5}-{\ln 3}\cdot{\ln 4}
\end{cases}$$$$

setting ${\ln x}=X$ and ${\ln y}=Y$ the folowing linear system is obtained:

$$\begin{cases}
{\ln 2}\cdot X-{\ln 3}\cdot Y=0 \\
{\ln 4}\cdot X-{\ln 5}\cdot Y={\ln 2}\cdot{\ln 5}-{\ln 3}\cdot{\ln 4}
\end{cases}$$

which holds to the following solutions

$$\begin{cases}
X= -{\ln 3}={\ln \frac13} \\
Y= -{\ln 2}={\ln \frac12}
\end{cases}$$

and finally

$$\begin{cases}
x=\frac13 \\
y=\frac12
\end{cases}$$

Comment: okay, thanks      for your help